# how to make 24 hour analog clock for android

Tags: android, clock

I have created an analog clock for android. But I want to make it a 24 hour clock. I want to display different things within the clock for different times within a 24 hour time period. For eg, I want to display something during dawn, something during night time etc. So for this reason I want to create a 24 hour clock.

One solution that I can think of is, customize the hour hand and minute hands. So that after one hour the hour hand rotates by only 15degrees instead of 30degrees. And the minute hand should rotate by 3degrees every minute instead of by 6 degrees.

But I dont see anything in the analog clock class to customize the rotations. Any clues would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should make this a custom view. I find it surprising that android even provides such a specific component in the base framework. Fortunately though, we can look at [source code for it, AnalogClock.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java).

Start with that code and modify it as needed. It's actually a pretty good example of how to implement a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a definite method to get time from Analog Clock Widget.

However you coloud use `DateFormat` to get time and on the basis of that time you can rotate your minute and hour hand by the method :-
`setRotation(float)` of Analog Clock Widget

Comment: Isnt that too much? If the app is open, I should keep checking the time every minute and keep rotating the hands? I dont know if this is practical

Comment: Your requirement is only to rotate the hands by some degress at a particular time. You can put multiple if else checks and rotate. This is the only way